# NestJS How to add custom Logger to custom ExceptionFilter

Tags: node.js, nest, nestjs

I am using NestJS 5.4.0
I have custom LoggerService, it's working perfectly. But, how can I add this LoggerService to ExceptionFilter.

```
// logger.service.ts
import {Injectable, LoggerService} from '@nestjs/common';
@Injectable()
export class Logger implements LoggerService {
    log(message: string) {
        console.log(message);
    }
    error(message: string, trace: string) {
        console.error(message);
    }
    warn(message: string) {
        console.warn(message);
    }
}

//logger.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import {Logger} from '../services/logger.service';
@Module({
    providers: [Logger],
    exports: [Logger],
})
export class LoggerModule {}


// user.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import {UserService} from '../services/user.service';
import {LoggerModule} from './logger.module';

@Module({
    imports: [LoggerModule],
    providers: [UserService],
    exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

It's working perfectly.

```
import {Logger} from './logger.service';
export class UserService {
    constructor(
        private logger: Logger
    ) {}
    private test = () => {
        this.logger.log("test"); // log success "test" to console
    }
}
```

But how can I add my custom Logger to ExceptionFilter

```
// forbidden.exception.filter.ts
import {HttpException, HttpStatus, Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class ForbiddenException extends HttpException {
    constructor(message?: string) {
        super(message || 'Forbidden', HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        // I want to add my custom logger here!
    }
}
```

Thank for reading.

Comment: The last part of the question makes it seem like you are trying to add logging to the `Exception` classes because you show the `ForbiddenException`.  Is that what you're trying to accomplish (i.e. log every time an `Exception` instance is instantiated), or do you instead want to use exception filters?  The nestjs documentation provides an example of an `HTTPExceptionFilter`: https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters

Comment: Those docs don't show how to inject a custom logger to a custom exception filter. I'm running into the same problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all your `class ForbiddenException extends HttpException` is not 
what it calls `ExceptionFilter`. `ExceptionFilter` is

> exceptions layer which is responsible for processing all unhandled exceptions across an application

[docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters)

**You provided exmaple when you are trying to inject it to your custom `HttpException`. But thats wrong. Your exception don't have to be responsible for logging. Thats what `ExceptionFilter` should be responsible for.**

Anyway, for now (17 oct 2019) there is no example in official docs how to inject providers to `ExceptionFilter`.

**You can pass it to `constructor` on init, but you should to get Logger instance before with `app.get<T>(...)` method.**

For example I've changed code from [exception-filters docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#exception-filters-1):

```
// HttpExceptionFilter.ts

import { ExceptionFilter, Catch, ArgumentsHost, HttpException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import {MyLogger} from '../MyLogger'

@Catch(HttpException)
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  constructor(private readonly logger: MyLogger) {}

  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
    const status = exception.getStatus();

    if (status >= 500) {
      this.logger.error({ request, response });
    }

    response
      .status(status)
      .json({
        statusCode: status,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        path: request.url,
      });
  }
}
```

and `bootstrap.ts` code:

```
// bootstrap.ts

const app = await NestFactory.create(MainModule, {
  logger: false,
});

const logger = app.get<MyLogger>(MyLogger);
app.useLogger(logger);
app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter(logger));
```

This technique can be used for all this `INestApplication` methods:

- app.useGlobalFilters
- app.useGlobalGuards
- app.useGlobalInterceptors
- app.useGlobalPipes
- app.useLogger
- app.useWebSocketAdapter

Answer (score 5):

First of all, to use dependency injection with Exception filters you cannot register them using the `useGlobalFilters()` method:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(MainModule, {
  logger: false,
});

const logger = app.get<MyLogger>(MyLogger);
app.useLogger(logger);

//Remove this line
//app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter(logger));
```

Next in your `MainModule`, add your custom exception filter as a provider (note: filters are automatically set as global no matter what module you add them to but as a best practice, add them to your top level module):

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_FILTER } from '@nestjs/core';
import { LoggerModule } from './logger.module';
import { ForbiddenException } from './forbidden.exception.filter.ts';

@Module({
  imports: [
    LoggerModule //this is your logger module
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_FILTER, //you have to use this custom provider
      useClass: ForbiddenException //this is your custom exception filter
    }
  ]
})
export class MainModule {}
```

Now you can inject the logger into your custom exception filter:

```
import {HttpException, HttpStatus, Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Logger } from './path/to/logger';

@Injectable()
export class ForbiddenException extends HttpException {

  constructor(private logger: Logger) {}

  catch(exception: HttpException, response) {
    this.logger.log('test');
  }
}
```

Pseudo code but I think you get the idea.